# Access content of vector registers in x86-64 assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, sse, simd

I'm trying to make octuple-precision floating points on x86-64, stored in `ymm` vector registers. But I only know how to access the lower 64 bits of `ymm0` (`vmovq`). How can I right-shift vector registers to access the other bits?
I've tested `vpsrlvd`, but it only worked with the `xmm` registers (I got "Illegal Instruction: 4" when I tested the `ymm` registers).

Comment: `vpsrlvd` is an integer AVX2 instruction that shifts bits within 32-bit elements, and is completely useless for you.  If your assembler accepted it but it faulted at runtime, probably your CPU only supports AVX1 (e.g. Intel before Haswell, or AMD before Excavator/Ryzen)

Comment: What you need are shuffles like [`vextractf128`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/VEXTRACTF128.html) or `vshufpd` to get data to the low element or low 128b lane, and `vmovq` or `vmovhpd`.

Comment: See more links in [the x86 tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) and [SSE tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sse/info) for guides on what's available.

Comment: @PeterCordes Ok, when I ran `sysctl -a | grep machdep.cpu.features` I couldn't find AVX2.0. I don't have support for the `ymm` registers.